# Usar metodo de listas

Tags: flutter, dart

soy nuevo en flutter y tenog este problema espero me puedan guiar, tengo este metodo que me regresa un array que consulta a la base de datos, neceisto obtener el resultado de ese array para recorrerlo pero el print que intento hacer solo me trae el texto : Instance of 'Future' espero puedan ayudarme gracias o como puedo obtener la lista del metodo consulta () en el return que hago la variable listopciones tiene todo el array pero fuera de este metodo no se como regresarlos gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: puedes poner el print en tu metodo `consulta` antes del `return`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una vez tuve ese problema y es que cuando dices `opctest = Future consulta()`. El resultado de la consulta es un token o una promesa de que en un futuro tendra un resultado.

Cuando usas los términos async y await le dices que espere a que cumpla esa promesa y asigna el resultado. Pero como no se utiliza ninguno de esos términos en initState. Solo te devuelve el token o la promesa o instancia de un futuro.

Lo que debes hacer es utilizar la otra forma de manejar futuros el método Then.

```
Future<List<Opciones>> consulta() {
....tu código....
}


Void initState(){
  súper.initState;
  conulta().then((value) {
    opctest = value;
    print(opctest);
    print(value); //esto es igual a opctest
  });
}
```

Al utilizar el otro método de manejar futuros .then le dices que espere a que se obtenga la respuesta del futuro primero y que luego maneje su valor resultante

Espero que te funcione. Creo que todos llegamos a pasar por esta situación en Flutter.